# Writing my own simple queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I have a function which looks something like:

```
void foo(){
    //Iterate through a file, line by line
    MyClass m = processSomething(line);
    callAnotherFoo(m);
}
```

and what I would like to do is have `processSomething(line)` actually push `m` on to a queue and `callAnotherFoo(m)` to take off of the queue and process.

I am a little unsure how I should proceed, especially as at the moment `processSomething()` and `callAnotherFoo()` are methods in the same class.

What design approach will I need to take? Will `callAnotherFoo()` need to be in a class of its own etc? I wanted to separate the queue implementation away from what `callAnotherFoo()` will do to the object from the queue.

**EDIT To be more specific I am referring to a queue used within a multithreaded environment- the part which is unclear is how my consumer will know when the queue has been populated and therefore knows when to remove/dequeue an object?**

Comment: You should seperate concerns. Your function `processSomething` doesn't imply it should also take care of a queue. It's bad idea to mix things that are not related. I advise you to read one of the books "Code Complete", "Clean Code: a Hand book of...", "Code Craft", or "Refactoring". Maybe you could call `callAnotherFoo(m, aQueue);`

Comment: instead of writing your own queue, have you considered using  std::queue<> ?

Comment: Apart from the obvious (use a standard library provided queue type) you need to spend some time learning how to use the [thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) in C++11. It is *not* something you're going to pick up in an hour of skimming, but is well worth the investment of time.

Comment: @WhozCraig C++ Concurrency in Action worth reading?

Comment: @user997112 I can't really comment on a book I haven't read, but so long as it is in-depth in covering the new C++11 classes, I'd say its worth a look. Ultimately you're best bang for buck will come from writing your own code and learning from that practice as well as other's *correct* code. Architecting a multi-level job-queue (which is what it looks like you're doing) isn't necessarily as trivial as it may first seem if you indeed are planning on keeping the cores as busy as possible. I'd say at least check it out from a library and give it a shot.